# split hours and minutes into number of 15 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 columns in my MySQL database - `hours` and `minutes`

i want to be able to split values into 15 minute segments using PHP.

for example, if i had a row that was:

```
hours = 1
minutes = 30
```

it would be `6 x 15 minutes`

if a row was

```
hours = 2
minutes = 0
```

it would be `8 x 15 minutes`

Comment: Maybe just store time as a single entity. But either way, this is a bit easy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This should return a number of 15-min segments

```
SELECT ROUND((hours*60+minutes)/15) AS segments FROM `table`
```

You can also use `CEIL` or `FLOOR` instead of `ROUND` to achieve a necessary rounding for non-integer segments.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC('1:30:00')/900,0) x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    6 |
+------+

SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC('2:00:00')/900,0) x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    8 |
+------+
```